# How do apply fuzzy lookup in r data frames

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames.
1. df1 is having sales data with unstructured headers, coming from OLAP cube.

```
df1 <- data.frame("[Time].[Fiscal Year].[Fiscal Year].[MEMBER_CAPTION]"= c("FY18","FY19","FY20"), "[Measures].[USD]"=c(100,200,300))
names(df1) <- c("[Time].[Fiscal Year].[Fiscal Year].[MEMBER_CAPTION]","[Measures].[USD]")
```

2. df2 is having list of unstructured headers and respective cleansed headers.

```
df2<- data.frame("RawHeaderName"=c("[Time].[Fiscal Year]","[Measures].[USD]"),"ReportDisplayName"=c("FiscalYear","USD"))
```

my requirement is when df2$RawHeaderName value matches (fuzzy matches) with df1 headers then i need to replace df1 headers with df2$ReportDisplayName value. Final out should be like below.

```
FinalOutput <- data.frame("FiscalYear" =c("FY18","FY19","FY20"),"USD"=c(100,200,300))
```

Please help me to solve the problem. 
I already tried with library("fuzzyjoin"),library("dplyr") libraries but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're simply looking for `names(df1) <- c('Fiscal Year', 'USD')` which modifies **df1** to:

```
  Fiscal Year USD
1        FY18 100
2        FY19 200
3        FY20 300
```

Comment: But how do handle when my requirement is dynamic ?

Comment: Haven't been able to get this working. Out of time for now.

Answer (score 0):

After speeding some time, below code is helping me to solve 50% problem only when match criteria exists. Still need to explore on fuzzy match.

library("dplyr")

```
df1 <- data.frame("[Time].[Fiscal Year].[Fiscal Year].[MEMBER_CAPTION]"= c("FY18","FY19","FY20"), "[Measures].[USD]"=c(100,200,300))
names(df1) <- c("[Time].[Fiscal Year].[Fiscal Year].[MEMBER_CAPTION]","[Measures].[USD]")


df2<- data.frame("RawHeaderName"=c("[Time].[Fiscal Year].[Fiscal Year].[MEMBER_CAPTION]","[Measures].[USD]"),"ReportDisplayName"=c("FiscalYear","USD"))


Extract_Headers <- (names(df1))
Extract_Headers <- data.frame("Headers"=as.character(Extract_Headers))
df2$RawHeaderName <- as.character(df2$RawHeaderName)
df2$ReportDisplayName <- as.character(df2$ReportDisplayName)
Cleansed_Headers <- Extract_Headers %>% inner_join (df2, by =c("Headers"="RawHeaderName"))
names(df1)<- Cleansed_Headers$ReportDisplay
```